# Delphi, FastReport params

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a problem with printing

```
procedure Sendparams(const Pparams,pparvalues :array of string);
begin
              for I := 0 to Length(Pparams) - 1 do
              begin
               lpar_name:=Pparams[i];
               lpar_val:=pparvalues[i] ;
               FfrxReport.Variables.AddVariable('Bez', lpar_name, lpar_val);
end;

Sendparams(['buyer','delivery'], ['buyer address', 'delivery address']);
```

Everything works fine until I try to print report; it says: Expression expected on Memo2.

```
Memo1.memo = '[buyer]';
Memo2.memo = '[delivery]';
```

memo1 and memo2 all other properties are the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: In send params I also call report FfrxReport.ShowReport(True);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possible traps.

1. If you want to use `Addvariable` (instead of `variables.add`) the category, in your case `Bez` has to be defined in the report, otherwise the variables won't be add. **
2. The assignment of the variables within the report hast to look like `Memo1.Lines.Text :=<buyer>;`
3. You will have to quote the string values of the variables
   `Sendparams(['buyer','delivery'], [QuotedStr('buyer address'), QuotedStr('delivery address')]);`

**[image]

Another attempt could be something like this, to avoid open arrays of string (where count of names and values accidentally could differ), to avoid a hard reference to the report within `Sendparams` and to deal with variables which already could be defined within the report.

```
Function PrepareReport(Report:TfrxReport; Variables: TfrxVariables;
                       ReportName: String):Boolean;// -- other parameters
var
 i,k:Integer;
begin
   // ....... other initializations

    if Assigned(Variables) then
      for i := 0 to Variables.Count - 1 do
      begin
        k := Report.Variables.IndexOf(Variables.Items[i].Name);
        if k > -1 then
          Report.Variables.Items[k].Value := Variables.Items[i].Value
        else
        begin
          with Report.Variables.Add do
          begin
            Name := Variables.Items[i].Name;
            Value := Variables.Items[i].Value;
          end;
        end;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: @ bummi, I have posted one question related to Fast Report which I am messing with at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635509/how-to-show-data-at-fast-report-in-33-grid-format) . Please take a look whenever possible.